# Symfony 4 - Can't load my css on some pages

Tags: css, symfony

I'm creating a website with Symfony 4.

But I've a page where my css and js don't load.
In the console, I've :

> GET http://localhost/symbnb/public/ads/css/bootstrap.min.css
>   net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
>
> maiores-nemo-excepturi-consectetur-saepe:40 GET
>   http://localhost/symbnb/public/ads/js/bootstrap.min.js
>   net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
>
> maiores-nemo-excepturi-consectetur-saepe:38 GET
>   http://localhost/symbnb/public/ads/js/jquery.min.js
>   net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
>
> maiores-nemo-excepturi-consectetur-saepe:39 GET
>   http://localhost/symbnb/public/ads/js/popper.min.js
>   net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

This error is at :

http://localhost/symbnb/public/ads/maiores-nemo-excepturi-consectetur-saepe

The files don't load.

But at

> http://localhost/symbnb/public/

and

> http://localhost/symbnb/public/ads/

All is good.

This is my files :

[image]
[image]

[image]

And if i put a / like :

> /css/bootstrap.min.js
>   /js/....

I've the error on all pages

Comment: You should use twig asset function : [Linking to assets](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I'm a beginner. What is the line that I have to use ? My css files aren't in asset folder

Comment: asset() will direct to public function, try to use what I answered

Answer (score 0):

Change your source by using **[Symfony twig asset function](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html).**

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Use it the same way for CSS asset.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="{{ asset('css/boostrap.min.css') }}">
```

Comment: So, I have to put my css and js files into the assets folder for that ?

Comment: I've this error : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Asset manifest file "C:\wamp64\www\symbnb/public/build/manifest.json" does not exist.").

Comment: Okay, I will install the asset

Comment: When I want to install that, I've :

  Problem 1
    - ocramius/proxy-manager 2.2.2 requires php ^7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - ocramius/proxy-manager 2.2.2 requires php ^7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - ocramius/proxy-manager 2.2.2 requires php ^7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for ocramius/proxy-manager (locked at 2.2.2) -> satisfiable by ocramius/proxy-manager[2.2.2].

Comment: You probably locked cramius/proxy-manager version to 2.2.2 in your composer json, modify it to 2.* or * and try to do it again.

Comment: In my composer.json, I haven't any cramius/proxy-manager. But I've a : "php":^7.1.3
I changed my wampserver php version to 7.2.1, but, can I change this "php":^7.1.3 to 7.2.1 manually ?

Comment: It's okay now. But the error is the same : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Asset manifest file "C:\wamp64\www\symbnb/public/build/manifest.json" does not exist.").

Comment: try to use bin/console assets:install

Comment: Same problem,, and "no assets  were provided by any bundle"

Answer (score 0):

Currently your website is looking for files in a folder that doesn't exist. Try to add a leading `/` to all of your assets. This should fix your issue.

Comment: If I add a "/", the problem is same but it is on all pages. I will try the Dylan's solution :)